# Words count in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a special case where (keeping less time complexity desirable) I need to count the number of times a word can be created from a given string. My code below only manages to get it once, if the words can be created more than once it fails. Any idea?

```
//String that needs to be searched
String s= "ccoptarra";

//Words that need to be found
String[] words = { "car", "pot", "bag" };

ArrayList count = new ArrayList();
HashMap map = new HashMap();
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    count.add(0);
    String w = words[i];
    map.put(w, "");
    for (int j = 0; j < w.length(); j++) {
        if (s.contains(String.valueOf(w.charAt(j)))) {
            map.put(w, map.get(w).toString() + w.charAt(j));
            if (map.get(w).equals(w))
                count.add(i, ((int)count.get(i)) + 1);
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < count.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("Word: " + words[i] + ", count = " + count.get(i));
```

**OutPut:**

```
Word: car, count = 1
Word: pot, count = 1
Word: bag, count = 0
```

Comment: You can use `replaceFirst` to replace all the characters from the original string, that are in the string to be searched when it is found. Then continue the search again.

Comment: I think count array is useless.
map.put(w,""); ==>  map.put(w. new Integer(1) );
and you can use Integer(1) as count. 
if(map.get(w).equals(w))
                map.put(w, map.get(w) +1 );  //like this

Comment: I'd probably create a map with the number of times a character is present in the string and then calculate based on that, i.e. there are 2 a, 2 c and 2 r in the string and car only needs one of each, so you could build it twice. That should also result in lower complexity.

Comment: Let me try that and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map to save every character and number of characters. After that just loop through the test words and select minimum number of character count from map for this word. Here is code

```
        //String that needs to be searched
    String s= "ccoptarra";

    //Words that need to be found
    String[] words = {"car","pot","bag"};

    List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (map.get(c) != null) {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j=0; j<words[i].length(); j++) {
            Integer value = map.get(words[i].charAt(j));
            if (value == null) {
                min = 0;
            } else if (value < min) {
                min = value;
            }
        }
        count.add(min == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? 0 : min);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<count.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Word: "+words[i]+", count = "+count.get(i));
```

Comment: Thanks this was just the small change I needed in my code

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand my commend as an answer to help you get the idea:

Step 1: Create some mapping to count the characters.

You could use an array with the character number as the index (subtract the value of 'a' to shift the offset to a = 0, b = 1 etc.). Or you could use a `Map<Character, Integer>`.

This should result in: a = 2, c = 2, o = 1, p = 1, r = 2, t = 1

Step 2: Repeat step 1 for each word you're looking for, e.g. for car you'd get a = 1, c = 1, r = 1 (for bag you'd have a = 1, b = 1, g = 1).

Step 3: for each character in the search word you calculate how often you'd fit the required number for the character into the available number (the integer part of the fraction) and get the minimum of all characters in the word.

Examples:

- car: a = 2/1 = 2, c = 2/1 = 2, r = 2/1 = 2 -> minimum is 2
- bag: a = 2/1 = 2, b = 0/1 = 0, g = 0/1 = 0 -> minimum is 0